# Intersection Observer classlist.toggle() not adding class

Tags: css, toggle, lazy-loading, svelte, intersection-observer

In the code below I am unsure why I cannot see my class 'show' being added in the DOM inspector. I only have styling for img. The class 'show' is not getting applied/toggled. MY goal is to lazy load images. I also need it to be compatible for webkit(safari). Thanks!

```
<script lang="ts">
    import { onMount } from 'svelte';
    export let image;

  
    let imageRef;

    //Lazy loading attempt...
    onMount(() => {
        //create observer, observe the target elements...
        const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
            (entries) => {

                //toggle the show class...
                entries[0].target.classList.toggle('show', entries[0].isIntersecting);
                //if element is now intersecting, stop observing it...
                if (entries[0].isIntersecting) {
                    observer.unobserve(entries[0].target);
                }
            },
            {
                threshold: 0.3, //30% of target needs to be visible
            },
        );
        observer.observe(imageRef);
    });

</script>

<img
    bind:this={imageRef}
    id="vodImage-{rowIndex}-{index}"
    aria-hidden="true"
    alt={title}
    src={image.uri}
    loading="lazy"
/>



<style lang="postcss"> <----tailwind css

    img {
        @apply w-full h-full opacity-0 duration-300;
        -webkit-animation-duration: 300ms;
    }

    .show {
        @apply opacity-100;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cannot reproduce the class not being added, the problem is probably that the CSS is being removed because Svelte does not detect the class being used.

DOM manipulation like that is not a good idea anyway, just use the native [`class:name` directive](https://svelte.dev/docs/element-directives#class-name) instead. `onMount` can also be replaced with an [action](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-action).

E.g.

```html
<script>
  // ...

  let show = false;

  function intersect(node) {
    const observer = new IntersectionObserver(
      entries => {
        show = entries[0].isIntersecting;

        if (show)
          observer.unobserve(node);
      },
      { threshold: 0.3 },
    );
    observer.observe(node);

    return {
      destroy: () => observer.disconnect(),
    };
  }
</script>

<img
  use:intersect
  class:show
  ...
```

Comment: This worked so I looked up the use: directive https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/actions and learned something new, and I thought about using the native class: so I am glad you said that. This makes way more sense now thanks wise sage!

Comment: The only problem is it doesn't work for webkit browser (safari) perhaps i need to add some webkit extensions?

Comment: I do not know what the issue with WebKit might be, `IntersectionObserver` is not exactly new, maybe there are divergences from the standard.